# Preventing character's movement if it won't fit(Unity2D)

Tags: unity

I'm creating a pacman game copy and I set up my movement. But there's a problem. My character can try to go up whenever I press but in the original you cannot go if there's a wall above you or your character won't fit.

[image]

For example in this situation you can still go up but you'll bounce off wall. So my question is how to prevent character from movement if there's a wall or it won't fit there.

Comment: I think you want a [circle cast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.CircleCast.html) there

Comment: I knew it will be something with raycasting. The thing is I don't understand how they work so I asked here ;D

Comment: How are you handling bounces off of walls? In order to predict that a bounce will occur, we need to know how your game currently decides something should bounce (eg. are you using Collider2D objects, or do you have your own map data structure that you check for walls?)

Comment: I do use box colliders on walls and circle collider on pacman (2D)

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use raycasting. The simplest solution would be adding    rigidbody2D to your pacman, and then apply some force to this body with AddForce(...) method when pressing button. PS Set gravity scale of body to 0.

Comment: That would result in the same behaviour OP describes as a problem they want to solve: the character tries to move into the wall and bounces off of it due to restitution.

Comment: The question was "my question is how to prevent character from movement if there's a wall or it won't fit there". Such prevention can be done by using collider2D and rigidbody2D.